# Prevent previously requests on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, ajax

I have list of tables,

```
<table id="<%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Certificate")%>" class="tbl_evenSearchResultRow" onmouseover="this.className='ResultGridRowSeleted'" onmouseout="this.className='tbl_evenSearchResultRow'" onclick="return SynopsisWindowOpen(this)">
```

onclick of each i use next function:

```
 function SynopsisWindowOpen(obj) {
var title = $(obj).find("strong[name='title']").html();

var isParentools = 0;
if (window.location.href.indexOf('recent_releases.aspx') > -1)
    isParentools = 1;

var url = "/ratings/Synopsis.aspx?logoonly=1&Certificate=" + obj.id + "&Title=" + encodeURIComponent(title) + "&parentools=" + isParentools;

$("#ratingModal").on("show.bs.modal", function (e) {
    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        cache: false,
        dataType: "html",
        success: function (data) {
            $("#ratingModal").find(".modal-body").html(data);
        }
    });
});
$("#ratingModal").on("hide.bs.modal", function (e) {
    $(this).find(".modal-body").html('');
});
$("#ratingModal").modal('show');

return false;
}
```

By url i render body of modal : i get certificate from request.query and according to it render body

```
LoadSynopsisContent(Request.QueryString["Certificate"], Request.QueryString["parentools"]);
```

Problem : when i click at first - everything seems to be good, on second click in modal body firstly rendered body of first click and then of second click. And so on. 
I don't know where is problem.

Firstly i use jquery `load` function, but then i change to simple ajax call with disabled caching.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move the all event bindings to outside of the function and everything should work fine.

Thus, these parts should not be inside the function:

```
$("#ratingModal").on("show.bs.modal", ....);

$("#ratingModal").on("hide.bs.modal", ....);
```

Here is one way you could organize your code:

```
var url; //a global variable ... not a good idea though
function SynopsisWindowOpen(obj) {
    ....
    url = .....
}

$(function() {
    $("#ratingModal").on("show.bs.modal", ....);

    $("#ratingModal").on("hide.bs.modal", ....);
});
```

However, the way would be to not use inline JavaScript but to take advantage of the power of jQuery to separate structure from behavior.

**UPDATE**

Instead of using a global variable `url` you can store the new url in a data attribute of the modal. Then you can get it from there when the modal opens.

In the function:

```
//calculate the url
var url = .....
//store the url in the modal
$('#ratingModal").data('table-url', url);
```

In the modal event handler:

```
$("#ratingModal").on("show.bs.modal", function(e) {
    //retrieve the url from the modal
    var url = $(this).data('table-url');
    //use the url
    $.ajax({ url: url, .... }):
});
```

Comment: Correct, that should do it although cluttering the global scope is not a good idea. If you're interested, I can suggest to you a better approach. @demo?